# If the function $f$ is holomorphic in a domain $Ω$ and $f'$ is identically zero throughout $Ω$ then $f$ is constant in $Ω$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

I'm not sure how to prove the following statement. I don't think it's meant to be very hard but I don't see a way to show it. If anyone could show me that would be a great help.

If the function $f$ is holomorphic in a domain $Ω$ and $f'$  is identically zero throughout $Ω$ then $f$ is constant in $Ω$.

Comment: This is not true in general unless $\Omega$ is connected.

Comment: $\Omega$ is a domain - so it is connected :)

Comment: It seems you are absolutely right, I confused myself in translating the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You can write every holomorphic function as a power series in a open neighbourhood and $f$ and $f'$ are holomorphic. So you just need to figure out what the coefficients are.

Comment: That answers the problem locally. Now to make a conclusion valid in $\Omega$, use the connectivity of $\Omega .$

Answer (score 0):

Any two points $a$, $b\in\Omega$ can be connected with a smooth curve
$$\gamma:\>[0,1]\to \Omega,\quad t\mapsto z(t),\qquad z(0)=a,\quad z(1)=b\ .$$
The auxiliary function $\phi(t):= f\bigl(z(t)\bigr)$ has derivative
$$\phi'(t)=f'\bigl(z(t)\bigr)\>z'(t)\equiv0\ .$$
Here we have used the chain rule and the assumption about $f$. It follows that $\phi$ is constant, so that
$$f(b)=f\bigl(z(1)\bigr)=\phi(1)=\phi(0)=f\bigl(z(0)\bigr)=f(a)\ .$$

Comment: Hi Christian thanks for taking the time to help me out. I think understand everything except for the last line - $f(b)=\phi(1)=\phi(0)=f(a)\ $. Would you mind explaining to me how you get this? I'm sure it's obvious but I'm just not seeing it I'm afraid. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Result from calculus: Suppose $g: \Omega \to \mathbb R,$ with $\nabla g = 0$ in $\Omega.$ Then $g$ is constant in $\Omega.$

On to our problem: Write $f= u+iv.$ Then $f'(z) = u_x(z) + iv_x(z) = v_y(z) -iu_y(z).$ Because $f'=0$ everywhere, $\nabla u, \nabla v \equiv 0$ in $\Omega.$ From the above, $u,v$ are constant in $\Omega.$

Comment: Concise and complete.  +1